# .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 assembly version conflict

Tags: .net-assembly, .net-4.5

My App.exe is compiled for .NET 4.5 and referencing SomeLib.dll which is a .NET 4.0 assembly which is referencing Reactive Extensions assembly (compiled for .NET 4.0).

My App.exe is also directly referencing Reactive Extensions assembly (compiled for .NET 4.5).
The Reactive Extensions assembly in the bin folder is .NET 4.5.

When trying to run the program, I got exception: Could not load file or assembly "System.Reactive.PlatformServices, Version 2.0.283.0 .... The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".

Is it possible to force the SomeLib.dll assembly to use RX for .NET 4.5 without recompiling it  for .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved when upgrading to RX 2.1